# How to update/upgrade a Facebook App API version on Facebook's Developers Panel? I even need to do it?

Tags: facebook, api, cakephp, sdk, version

I received, recently, an e-mail from Facebook telling me that my APP is doing some deprecated calls that will stop working on August, 8th

Using the Facebook API Migration Tool, it shows me no calls to older APIs, so, I am good to go

I use the Facebook PHP SDK in my application and all places where "graph_version" appears, it is forced to v2.5

In Facebook's Developers Dashboard, my APP is showing API version 2.0 (was the API at the creation time)

So, do I need to worry? When the date comes, will my APP API Version change automaticly? How can I update my APP info on Dashboard to set the API version to 2.5 or above?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What the app dashboard shows is only the _minimum_ API version your app can use. If you are explicitly specifying v2.5 in your SDK initialization, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can upgrade the Facebook API version of your app simply by going to the app dashboard, then `Settings -> Advanced (in a drop-down menu under Settings)` or use the URL: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID_HERE/settings/advanced/

Comment: So does it means even your app is targetting to an older API version, facebook would redirect these calls to the version that you choose from the drop-down?

Comment: yes. Just checked it. My NodeJS module has v2.3 by default and when I fire a request to FB graph api, in response headers I see `'facebook-api-version': 'v2.11'` - it means this version v2.11 processed my request. Also, I have v2.11 in my `Settings -> Advanced` dropdown. If I force to use version above v2.11, for example, I set v3.0 by default in the module, facebook processes my request with v3.0

Answer (score 0):

If you press on the "?" mark, you will see that this is the oldest version your app can call. It means you can use any versions that newer than this version, all older versions can not be used.
So you'll be ok.